# Use createPrimaryIndex with Mock

Tags: couchbase

I try to use couchbase.Mock in my unit test with the couchbase nodejs SDK. But i have this error :

> createPrimaryIndex is not a function

with this code:

```
cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(options.protocol + "://" + options.server + ":" + options.port);
open().then(() => createPrimaryIndex());

function open() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket = cluster.openBucket(options.bucketName, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

function createPrimaryIndex() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bucket.manager().createPrimaryIndex({
            ignoreIfExists: true
        }, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It work perfectly when i use couchbase but it fail if i use couchbase.Mock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all functions are implemented by the mock.

See this forum post regarding a similar issue and a workaround using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org):

[Node.js Mock N1QL Query Support](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/node-js-mock-n1ql-query-support/5811?u=jkurtz)

Comment: Ok, I was deceived by the [release note of v2.3.7](https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/nodejs-sdk#story-h2-3)